# Веб-сервер из точки доступа на андроид

Tags: android, сервер, веб-сервер

мне бы хотелось узнать, возможно ли ,включив со своего android точку доступа, другим пользователям (этой точки доступа) дать возможность зайти на сайт лежащий на моём android , сделать некое подобие сервера.
Если возможно ,то как это сделать?

Comment: Можно. Есть нюансы. Например если система, решит что сервер занимает много ресурсов, которые надо использовать для более важных вещей, она его кильнёт. В целом пример реализации такого сервера есть здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43775284/8343843

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться программой [Tiny Web Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ar.com.lrusso.tinywebserver). После того как вы установите данное приложение, необходимо провести конфигурацию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

дальше вы настраиваете папку которую хотите сделать как хранилище:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и дальше вы можете наслаждаться результатом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Вот тут](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/turn-android-device-web-server/) первоисточник. Аналогичные статьи: [1](https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-make-an-android-server/), [2](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/android-web-server), [3](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-easily-install-a-web-server-on-an-android-device/) и [4](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-turn-an-android-device-into-a-web-server). Вопросы на enSO: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509851/web-server-for-android) и [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244285/how-to-create-a-simplest-web-server-in-android).